# GWT Development mode with jetty Not running

Tags: gwt

I installed a new Eclipse ,
Installed GWT plugin 2.8.1 from marketplace ,
Right click project run as GWT Development mode with Jetty..

After that i just keep getting message "Waiting for Launch Urls.."

Console Is totally empty , nothing in console. Not a single message .

Any idea what gone wrong

Comment: Latest Eclipse requires Java 11, Jetty 9.2 does not run with Java 11.

Answer (score 1):

The latest Java version and the GWT supported version of Jetty are incompatible. Using **Tomcat** in Eclipse is a good way to go around this:

Window -> Show View -> Servers

In Servers New -> Server -> Choose apache tomcat

Point to the location of your tomcat installation/download Next

Add your gwt-maven project which will add the target/project.war to the tomcat modules. Save it.

Then you just need to start the server. When the development server starts, it should give you the development URL to browse to.